# ESP8266 Serial USB adapter doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, serial, microcontroller

So I need to program a little ESP8266 microcontroller with the Arduino IDE. But the board which is connected with a Serial-to-USB Adapter won't get detected by my Ubuntu system. 
The adapter: https://www.ebay.de/itm/USB-to-ESP8266-Serial-Wireless-Wifi-Module-Developent-Board-8266-Wifi-Adapter-/192035277895

I've run dmesg after plugging both in and got these results:

```
[  198.724616] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  198.873179] usb 3-2: config 1 has 0 interfaces, different from the descriptor's value: 1
[  198.873763] usb 3-2: language id specifier not provided by device, defaulting to English
[  198.874001] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=5503, bcdDevice= 2.54
[  198.874004] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
SERIAL.874007] usb 3-2: Product: USB
```

I've installed the board manager on the Arduino IDE and even an extra driver for the CH430. But still the board has no tty mark or something like this.
Any help appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does that board actually have USB<->serial, or is USB used just for power. Is there a resource documenting it, because eBay listing doesn't have a lot of info?

Comment: @domen actually I bought the board from the German eBay so it was another listing. But where I bought it, it's said in the headline to be a programmer with a serial Interface, so it should work, I wanted to try it tomorrow or in the near future on a Windows PC and see if it works there